# jiffy lube oil change problems?

Tags: honda, repair, oil-pan

Jiffy lube stripped my oil pan  and it is costing me $500  to repair my Honda Accord 2011 according to my other mechanic. Am I being ripped off?

Comment: If the drain plug is stripped and you end up having to foot the bill, ask your mechanic about possibly using an adapter or rethreading and using a larger plug bolt. With an adapter he'd drill to a slightly larger size, tap the hole (rethread the hole), and put an adapter in to adapt it back down to the original size. Either way (unsolicited personal opinion incoming), stay away from Jiffy Lube; find a mechanic you trust and stick with them.

Answer (score 1):

Can you *prove* that Jiffy Lube damaged your oil pan? Unlikely that you can, but if so, then they should be paying for the repairs.

To replace an oil pan in a Honda Accord involves purchasing the new pan, disconnecting the suspension, raising the engine, cutting off the new pan gasket, and the reverse to refit. Quite possibly a front-end alignment may be needed also. I'd call it pretty much a 6hour job to do it, plus parts.

Comment: And most of the price is probably labor.